# Autohotkey GUI buttons changed size on a different PC

Tags: user-interface, screen, autohotkey, monitor

I am not so familiar with this aspect of autohotkey. A while back I wrote a GUI that worked on both my laptop and my docking station monitor. Recently I replaced my existing monitor with a larger one. Now my buttons appear too small for the text, and there are a few other changes to the positioning of the window.

I am wanting to be able to have my GUI work properly between the laptop by itself and when it's docked.

Also please explain to me what caused this.

Answer (score 1):

Some examples.

```
Gui, Add, Button, gButtons vButton1, Button1  |  auto position and size
Gui, Add, Button,y+40 gButtons vButton2, Button 2  |  y is relative to Button1 +40 ;same x as Button1
Gui, Add, Button,x+60 gButtons vButton3, Button 3  |  x is relative to Button2 +60 ;same y as Button2
Gui, Add, Button, x200 y200 gButtons vButton4, Button 4  |  Fixed position x=200 y=200
Gui, Add, Button, x15 y250 w200 h60 gButtons vButton5, Button 5  |  Fixed position, width and hight
Gui, Add, Button, y+20 wp+100 hp-30 gButtons vButton6, Button 6  |  Relative y, width and hight to button 5 width increased +100 and h decreased by 30
Gui, Add, Button, y+20 wp hp gButtons vButton7, Button 7  |  Relative y, and same width and hight as button 5
Gui, Add, Button, y+20 wp w150 h30 gButtons vButton8, Button 8  |  Mistake too much text and w and h are fixed and too small
Gui, Add, Button,x+10 gButtons vButton9, Button 9 |  A lot of text but w`nand h are not fixed ;if you dont put new line it would all go in 1 line
Gui,Add,Button,x240 y480 gGuiClose,Exit
Gui, Show, w500 h500
return

GuiClose:
ExitApp

Buttons:
return
```

More info about Positioning and Sizing of Controls on
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#PosSize

Comment: Thank you for the info. I didn't know about that. Unfortunately none of these apply to my problem because every X and Y, H and W is fixed.  but the buttons seemed to be too small on the new monitor.

Comment: Try removing fixed values for H and W and see if it helps. Then button size should be as big as necessary for text to be showed correctly no matter which monitor is used.